# how to get between dates with time ago in java

Tags: java, date, java-stream

I need dates within the specified time.

Ex 1:
Let my current time instance : 15-06-2018 08:00AM
If i give 24hours ago as input, I need dates as 14-06-2018 and 15-06-2018 as 24hrs from my current instance means yesterday date too.

Ex 2:
Let my current time instance : 15-06-2018 08:00AM
If i give 7hours ago as input, I need dates as 15-06-2018 as 7hrs from my current instance means only today date.

I tried of using below code but not giving results as expected. Please suggest if there is any better approach to make this:

```
pre = LocalDateTime.now().minusMinutes(duration);
numOfDaysBetween = ChronoUnit.DAYS.between(pre, 
LocalDateTime.now().plusDays(1));
System.out.println(numOfDaysBetween);
if (numOfDaysBetween > 0) {
            dateList = IntStream.iterate(0, i -> i + 1).limit(numOfDaysBetween).mapToObj(i -> pre.plusDays(i)).collect(Collectors.toList());
            for (LocalDateTime d : dateList) {
                System.out.println(String.format("%04d", d.getYear()) + "." + String.format("%02d", d.getMonthValue()) + "." + String.format("%02d", d.getDayOfMonth()));
            }
        }
```

Comment: `plus/minusHours`?

Comment: ago hours... minus i need. anytime duration i give as input should  perform ago operations from current time.

Comment: Well I know in C# on a DateTime this would work -- plusDays(-N). Not sure about Java but I figure it's similar. Then you can iterate the days .plusDays(1) while currDay < finalDay and add them to a list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
LocalDateTime now = LocalDateTime.parse("2018-06-21T08:40:00.00Z", DateTimeFormatter.ISO_OFFSET_DATE_TIME);
LocalDateTime then = now.minusHours(7);
LocalDate start;
LocalDate target;
int delta = 1;
if (then.isBefore(now)) {
    start = then.toLocalDate();
    target = now.toLocalDate();
    delta = 1;
} else {
    start = now.toLocalDate();
    target = then.toLocalDate();
    delta = -1;
}
target = target.plusDays(1);
while (start.isBefore(target)) {
    System.out.println(start);
    start = start.plusDays(delta);
}
```

Input/output results...

```
+-------+------------+
| Input |   Output   |
+-------+------------+
|    24 | 2018-06-20 |
|       | 2018-06-21 |
+-------+------------+
|     9 | 2018-06-20 |
|       | 2018-06-21 |
+-------+------------+
|     7 | 2018-06-21 |
+-------+------------+
```

Although, if you want to avoid the oddities of daylight savings, you might consider using something more like...

```
Instant now = Instant.parse("2018-06-21T08:40:00.00Z");
Instant then = now.minus(9, ChronoUnit.HOURS);
Instant start;
Instant target;
int delta = 1;
if (then.isBefore(now)) {
    start = then;
    target = now;
} else {
    start = now;
    target = then;
    delta = -1;
}
if (!target.truncatedTo(ChronoUnit.DAYS).equals(start.truncatedTo(ChronoUnit.DAYS))) {
    target = target.plus(1, ChronoUnit.DAYS);
}
while (start.isBefore(target)) {
    System.out.println(start);
    start = start.plus(delta, ChronoUnit.DAYS);
}
```

Input/output results

```
+-------+----------------------+
| Input |        Output        |
+-------+----------------------+
|    24 | 2018-06-20T08:40:00Z |
|       | 2018-06-21T08:40:00Z |
+-------+----------------------+
|     9 | 2018-06-20T23:40:00Z |
|       | 2018-06-21T23:40:00Z |
+-------+----------------------+
|     7 | 2018-06-21T01:40:00Z |
+-------+----------------------+
```

Comment: First code snippet worked like charm with all sort of inputs m getting expected output. Thanks @MadProgrammer. But with second code snippet for current instance as 8:40, using 9 hours ago giving me output as only today date. ideally it should give me today and yesterday which m getting with first snippet

Comment: It could be an issue with daylight savings

Comment: ideally time instance or localdatetime consider my local machine time zone right? or UTC in general?

Comment: Part of the problem is, -9 hours isn't technically a "days" difference (returns `0` days). Not sure how to fix the `Instant`, might have fix for `LocalDat`

Comment: I am trying to understand, correct me if i am wrong.. First snippet we were using if date occurs before or not with target time and we increment a day accordingly.. With second snippet if difference between days which not gives expected results. Is this the scenario? Glad if u please explain first snippet

Comment: I've updated both approaches, testing 24, 9 and 7 hour differences. With the first approach, we don't need to deal with the "time" component, makes it easier to deal with comparisons, the second does and suffers for it - but you can "truncate" the time values, which should give you more control

Answer (score 1):

This is what the [`LocalDate.datesUntil` method introduced in Java 9](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html#datesUntil-java.time.LocalDate-) is for.

```
    ZoneId zone = ZoneId.of("Australia/Sydney");
    ZonedDateTime now = ZonedDateTime.now(zone);
    Duration duration = Duration.ofHours(16);
    LocalDate preDate = now.minus(duration).toLocalDate();
    LocalDate endExclusive = now.toLocalDate().plusDays(1);
    List<LocalDate> dateList 
            = preDate.datesUntil(endExclusive).collect(Collectors.toList());
    System.out.println(dateList);
```

Running just now (14:30 in Sydney) I got this result:

> [2018-06-20, 2018-06-21]

Other tricks: Use `ZonedDateTime` for finding the start. There will be corner cases, for example at transistion to and from summer time (DST) where `LocalDateTime` will not give you the correct result.

And specify time zone explicitly. Even if you just specify `ZoneId.systemDefault()` you are telling the reader — and yourself — that you have made a conscious choice of time zone to use.

### What went wrong in your code?

There are 0 days between now and 7 hours ago. Or 23 hours ago, for that matter. `ChronoUnit.DAYS.between` only counts whole days. To get the correct number of dates you would need to convert to `LocalDate` before counting.